# Replicar datos en la misma tabla actualizando los nuevos datos

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, oracle

Tengo el siguiente problema, tengo una tabla con la siguiente estructura

```
id  | dir | codigo       | id_padre
304 | 420 | cod-TNAB0001 | 305
305 | 420 | cod-TNIQ002  |  
306 | 420 | cod-TNBIF001 | 307
307 | 420 | cod-TNQB004  |
308 | 420 | cod-TNIA001  |
309 | 420 | cod-TNQB010  | 308
310 | 420 | cod-TNASH0019| 312
311 | 420 | cod-TNASH0029| 312
312 | 420 | cod-TNCJ002  |
```

Lo que necesito es ingresar los mismos datos, en la misma tabla pero actualizando el id_padre con el nuevo id luego de la insercion es decir algo asi:

```
id  | dir | codigo       | id_padre
313 | 450 | cod-TNAB0001 | 314
314 | 450 | cod-TNIQ002  |  
315 | 450 | cod-TNBIF001 | 316
316 | 450 | cod-TNQB004  |
317 | 450 | cod-TNIA001  |
318 | 450 | cod-TNQB010  | 317
319 | 450 | cod-TNASH0019| 321
320 | 450 | cod-TNASH0029| 321
321 | 450 | cod-TNCJ002  |
```

La inserción la realizo con el siguiente código:

```
insert into tabla(ID, dir, CODIGO, ID_PADRE)
select SEQ_TABLA.NEXTVAL, 450, CODIGO, ID_PADRE
FROM tabla where evn_id = 420;
```

Lo que no se como hacer es la actualización de los id_padre.

**¿Cómo podría actualizar esta columna?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que lamentablemente vas a tener que pasar por una tabla temporal. Sería ideal poder usar `sequence` en una subconsulta, pero hasta dónde sé, no se puede. Por este motivo la idea sería la siguiente:

1. Creas una tabla temporal similar a la original, con una nueva columna `id_nuevo`
2. Completas esta tabla con tu consulta, materializas en ésta, el `id_nuevo`, y, muy importante, mantienes también el `id` actual
3. Por último, usamos recursivamente en una consulta esta nueva tabla, para poder "ubicar" el `nuevo_id` que le correspondería al `id_padre`

Esa es la idea, trataré de implementarla de manera bien simplificada, espero que  quede claro:

#### Esta sería la estructura del ejemplo:

```
-- Tabla original
create table ejemplo (id int, id_padre int);
-- Copia de trabajo de la tabla original
create table ejemplo_tmp (id_nuevo int, id int, id_padre int);
create sequence seq;

-- Apenas dos filas de ejemplo, pero alcanzan
insert into ejemplo (id, id_padre) values(304, 305);
insert into ejemplo (id, id_padre) values(305, NULL);
```

#### Llenamos la tabla temporal

```
insert into ejemplo_tmp (id, id_nuevo, id_padre)
SELECT id,
       -- generamos un nuevo id (id + 400)
       400 + seq.NEXTVAL AS id_nuevo, 
       id_padre
       FROM ejemplo,
            dual
;
```

#### Por último, generamos la consulta de inserción (solo faltaría agregar el `insert`):

```
-- la tabla original
select * from ejemplo;

|  ID | ID_PADRE |
|-----|----------|
| 304 |      305 |
| 305 |   (null) |

-- Y los valores re-indizados
select t1.id_nuevo as id,
       t2.id_nuevo as id_padre
       from ejemplo_tmp t1
       left join ejemplo_tmp t2
            on t1.id = t2.id_padre;

|  ID | ID_PADRE |
|-----|----------|
| 408 |      407 |
| 407 |   (null) |
```

#### Comentarios finales;

- Si vas a hacer algo así, mas que recomendable meter todo en una transacción
- Dependiendo del volumen, esto podría llegar a requerir que agregues al menos un índice en el `id`.

Comment: Genial, me sirvió tu respuesta, aunque tambien estuve pensando en hacer algo con un lenguaje de programación como alternativa